# find the n-th smallest value in an unsorted array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, recursion, indexing

I need to find the n-th smallest value in an unsorted array, without sorting it of course.
The function needs to be recursive.
I thought about the code below but that doesn't work, because I can miss some of the values in the small arrays. any suggestions ?

Examples:

```
array ={5,2,10,11,18,3,7,9,15,17}
index = 3
expected return = 7
    
index=7
expected return = 15
```

---

```
int func(int arr[], int size, int index)
{
  //if we cant divide the array anymore
  if (size == 1)
    return arr[0];

  //if we don't need to divide the array anymore
  if (index == 1)
    return findMinInArr(arr, size);

  //split the array to 2 arrays and work on lower level
  return Max(func(arr, size / 2, index / 2), func(arr + size / 2, size - size / 2, index - index / 2));

}
```

Comment: @יונתן אליהו What is the n-th value?

Comment: @יונתן אליהו And why the function does need to be recursive?

Comment: sorry, adding an example in a minute.

Comment: 1. Are the values all distinct? 2. Is this a homework assignment question?

Comment: Im practicing recusion.

Comment: yes and yes thats a HW assigment q.

Comment: FYI, for anybody who sees this question in the future and wants to search for related information, algorithms for finding the nth largest/smallest item in a list or array are called [selection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Answer (score 4):

Your approach fails because there is no reason for the partition into halves to be meaningful w.r.t. finding your value of interest.

For example, suppose you need the 2nd smallest value. It could be the case that the smallest and second-smallest values are *both* in the first half of the array; and the second half only has very large values. Your use of `Max()` will result in your function returning one of these values.

Instead, consider:

1. If the values are all distinct, implementing a function to find the smallest value that's no smaller than a given value, and using that as a building-block.
2. Partially-sorting the array, using one of the sorting algorithms you have likely learned about already.

These are hints, as I suspect you're asking us about a "homework question" and you should make the effort to solve it on your own.

Comment: I will try that, tnx.

Comment: @יונתןאליהו: In that case, you may consider accepting this answer by clicking the 'V' sign. On StackOverflow, that if the more meaningful act; there is no need to thank us.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going in the wrong way, trying to divide your array.

I would like to replace the smallest number in your array by `INT_MAX`, so the idea is to do something like (pseudo-code):

```
int get_smallest(array, index)
{
  if index==0 
  then return smallest(array);
  else
  {
    replace_smallest_number_by_INT_MAX(array);
    return get_smallest(array, index - 1);
  }
}
```

So, when you run this, you would have a behaviour like this:

```
  get_smallest({5      , 2      , 10, 11, 18, 3      , 7, 9, 15, 17}, 3)
= get_smallest({5      , INT_MAX, 10, 11, 18, 3      , 7, 9, 15, 17}, 2)
= get_smallest({5      , INT_MAX, 10, 11, 18, INT_MAX, 7, 9, 15, 17}, 1)
= get_smallest({INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 10, 11, 18, INT_MAX, 7, 9, 15, 17}, 0)
= 7
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [FAQ item](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on meta about answering homework questions ?

Comment: @einpoklum: First of all, I am not aware this is a homework question. Next to that, I don't see a breach in the code of conduct here: the author clearly has a wrong algorithm in mind and I show an example of how a good algorithm might look like. By doing this, I'm using pseudo-code (there is no `then` in C and the functions `smallest()` and `replace_...()` are not implemented). Why do you think I'm breaching the code of conduct concerning homework questions?

Comment: I wasn't making any accusations, I was just asking, so that if you were not aware of the guidelines/discussion on Meta, you'd go have a look. Finally, note OP has said (in a comment) that it is a homework question.

Comment: @einpoklum: No problem. I had not seen that comment indeed, but personally for me it won't make a difference: if a person does an effort and is stuck at a specific problem, I might answer with a complete piece of source code. If a person shows no effort or seems not to have a clue, I might give some pseudocode as a starting point (which I did here). Although I am aware of the FAQ concerning homework questions, I adopt that same attitude for all kinds of questions.